# AWS: How to configure IAM role for EC2 as a web server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver, amazon-iam

I plan to deploy my Yii2 PHP website to an AWS EC2 instance that will connect to an RDS instance for the database.

I am on "Step 3: Configure Instance Details" and it is asking for IAM role. All tutorials on YouTube say this is important for production, but don't go into how I should configure this.

Why would I need to create an IAM role for my EC2 that will act as a web server only? I guess it is to let it access RDS, if I am not mistaken.

Can someone list the steps or a tutorial on what role I'd need to create and assign, if I want to use the EC2 as a web server.

Comment: You can only assign a role when the instance is created, and they can be useful. For example, you can give the role access to a particular S3 bucket so it can create or download files there. Even if you don't have a need for it *now*, it's good to have it in place if the need arises so you don't have to replace the whole instance.

Comment: AWS article help you to undersatand more https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html

Comment: You will need to create a custom Policy attaching access to RDS resource and then create the Role and attach your custom Policy.
EDIT:
You also need to create a custom Security Group and allow only inbound to the HTTP(s) ports.

Comment: So, should I just create an EC2 instance for now, without any roles assigned?

Comment: @ShahidThaika I would create an empty role. You don't have to give the role any permissions; just create a `webserver` role in IAM and pick it when creating the instance. That way, you can add permissions to the role *later* without needing to fire up a new server.

Comment: A recent change to Amazon EC2 allows you to add or remove a role at any time. If your web server has no need make any AWS API calls, it does not need a role.